# New learner of react

Tags: reactjs, components

I am learning react and have been doing a course with Codecademy. Now I’m playing around on my own and just trying to pick stuff up.

Say I have a few lists saved. Eg

- Athletes
- Coaches
- Teams
- etc

And I have a parent page. 
And I want the user to be able to search for say athletes in a certain state or postcode etc.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get started. 
I'm guessing I need to use props. And if statements or something along those lines, but being new it’s all to overwhelming at the moment.

If someone could help me to get started or point me in the direction of where I could get more info that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a parent that gets the search input values from the user and pass the search values to the child component.

```
class Parent extends Component {

  state = {
    state: '',
    postal: ''
  }

  // Search terms from the user
  // You decide how you should get these values
  search(state, postal) {
    this.setState({ state, postal })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* Pass your search terms to your child */}
        <MyChild state={ this.state.state } postal={ this.state.postal } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The child component will get these search values through props and check if they exist in a list that you define.

```
class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super()
  }

  // check if item exists in list
  check() {
    // Get props
    const { state, postal } = this.props
    // Search through list
    return list.find(item => {
      if (state === item.state) { return item.name }
      if (postal === item.postal) { return item.name }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // render the name of the athelete
        <p>{ this.check() }</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent gives me something to work from. Thank you very much dan. 